# Formatted output - same data to multiple text file in C

Tags: c, text, file-io, formatted-text

The program I am working generates data which I output to text files using fprintf_s() function.

For a certain reasons I need to print the "same" data to different text files (with different names), so I was wondering if I can accomplish them by calling the fprintf_s() once only or maybe some other method or function.

To clarify my question I am providing a silly example:

```
number = 100; FILE fp1, fp2,

fopen_s(&fp1,"file01.txt","w"); fopen_s(&fp2,"file02.txt","w");

//Instead of doing this

fprintf_s(fp1,"I want to print this number = %d\n", number); 

fprintf_s(fp2,"I want to print this number = %d\n", number);

// Can I do something like this... 

fprintf_s(fp1,fp2,"I want to print this number = %d\n", number);

// I know the above line doesn't work.
```

Comment: You can work with only one file and then simple copy it or not?

Comment: You can put the `FILE` pointers in an array and use a `for` loop to write the data out.

Comment: @duDE Well true, if the content were exactly same, I could have done that but they are not. For example, maybe I want to put headers of tables which are all the same but the contents of the table might differ. Including fprintf_s for all the different files is making my code very messy. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

So you wanna refactor, hein?

```
int multi_printf_s(FILE **fs, size_t n, const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list argz;
    int ret;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        va_start(argz, fmt);
        ret = vfprintf_s(fs[i], fmt, argz);
        va_end(argz);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Calling:

```
FILE *f1 = fopen(...); // whatever
FILE *f2 = fopen(...);
FILE *f3 = fopen(...);
FILE *f4 = fopen(...);

FILE *fs[] = { f1, f2, f3, f4 };
multi_printf_s(fs, sizeof(fs) / sizeof(fs[0]), "Print this: %d\n", 42);

// don't forget to fclose()!
```